# Change location if POST is 0

Tags: php, post, location

I got this variable:

```
$page = (int) $_REQUEST['page'];
```

I need some actions that will base on the above request. This will be used to the pagination script.

I mean:

if `$page` is 0 , then script will redirect the user to the another subpage.
The trick is that I need to redirect user ONLY in case if in his URL `&page=0` is specified, otherwise, it won't do anything.

I've tried this:

```
if( $page == 0 ) {
header("Location; xxxx");
}
```

but it does redirect the user even if he did not specified (or POST the page).

So , how can I do that?

Comment: The problem is that because you are casting to an int, an empty value will be converted to 0, which happens when no page is requested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This checks if it is actually set by user, and it is `0`

```
if (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && $_REQUEST['page'] === 0)
{
    header('Location: xx');
}
```

Do 3: `===` to check if value is actually the number 0

Comment: Oh , thank you. I was using similar way: `if (isset($post)) && $page == 0` but it didn't worked. Your example works like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

use strict comparison:

```
if ($page === "0"){
...
}
```

updated.

well I would be more strict. I would use following approach

```
if (isset($_POST["page"])){
   $page = (int) $_POST["page"];
   /* do you assumptions here. this will definitely work */
}
```

Comment: if `$page` is typecast as `(int)` it will never be literally a string version of zero.

Comment: Doesn't work - if haven't specified the &page in the URL, it returns true.

Answer (score 0):

See [array_key_exists](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php):

```
array_key_exists($_REQUEST, 'page'); // returns false if no 'page' parameter supplied.
```

Answer (score 0):

You should compare the `0` as a string value, therefore you should read `$page` from `$_REQUEST` as a string value too...

```
<?php
 $page = $_REQUEST['page'];
 if( $page == "0" ) {
   header("Location: ./?did-it");
 }
?>
```

ps - I think `Location; ...` should be with colon like `Location: ...`

Answer (score 0):

Change the semicolon to colon.

```
header("Location; xxxx");
```

should be:

```
header("Location: xxxx");
```

Now, additional info on comparison operators as I disagree with @jancha answer

> `===`: TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
>
> `==`: TRUE if $a is equal to $b after [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php).

This is the same in JavaScript. An example of how this is useful is when you want different code to run on false/0 and on undefined (say for error handling), in this case we can do a much simpler test.

```
$page = (int) $_REQUEST['page']; //this is the line to change
```

change to

```
//this way you don't need to type cast it (which is only supported with php5.3+)
$page = (isset($_REQUEST['page']) && is_numeric($_REQUEST['page'])) ? $_REQUEST['page']:0;
```